# What is the Biblical basis for the idea that God doesn't have form?

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-god

In Genesis, God walks on the garden of Eden. Israelites saw a sapphire throne below God's feet. Ezekiel saw a throne and someone sitting on it. So is John in revelation. In Mamre, Abraham saw 3 guys, and Christians believe one of them is God. [Does God have a form as seen by John the Apostle?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/23949/does-god-have-a-form-as-seen-by-john-the-apostle?rq=1)

I saw some atheist sites, that interpret the Bible based on what it actually says, even think that Abraham must have seen 3 gods, El Shaddai, Yahweh, and maybe Elyon, coming to Abraham.

In any case, several times in the bible, God is described as having form. People just can't see it because they die if they do.

Yet many believe that God has no form. What verses in the Bible are used to say, "God has no form"?

Comment: It seems to me that you are automatically taking a *sola scriptura* approach. Some Christians do not take a *sola scriptura* approach in biblical interpretation; they rely on their well-informed, educated priests to interpret the scriptures for them. It would be helpful, if you could cite those "atheist" sites. Those atheists you mention are implicitly taking a *sola scriptura* approach to the Bible.

Comment: Based on this meta post: ["Biblical basis" vs "what the Bible says about a subject"](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3958) this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: `Yet we all believe...` We don't *all* believe *anything*.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that this question is opinion based based on the exact same meta post listed. What the bible says about something is, I agree, opinion based. Where in the bible does it says something is not.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question.  1 John 4:12, John 1:18, & 1 Timothy 6:16 all cross reference each other and all say that God (the Father in this case; I'll get to this later) has not been seen, and cannot be seen.  It doesn't directly say formless, but we interpret it that way as something that can't be seen would logically lack form.

Now, you raised some good points about God walking in Eden, the Israelites seeing someone seated on a throne, etc., but that diverges from your question of God being formless into a discussion on the Trinity.  The member/person of the Godhead (Father, Son, & Holy Spirit) that is referenced in the verses I referred to is God the Father, and He has never been, nor will ever be, seen.  Again, a discussion on the Trinity is a whole new question for another time, and really should be a separate question, but I hope this is simple enough to reference for your question.

Awesome question by the way, IMHO.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Comment: Thanks David, that gives me a better idea of the format around here, I appreciate it.

Comment: I'd also just like to add that my three verses were the reference points here, but thanks.

Comment: 1 Timothy 6:16 "...dwelling in unapproachable light..." Hence why we can't see him, not because he's the formless blob god of the philosophers.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in the Bible that directly addresses the issue of the "form of God" is Deuteronomy chapter 4.

> "Then the LORD spoke to you out of the midst of the fire; **you heard
>   the sound of words, but saw no form**; there was only a voice" (Deut
>   4:12)
>
> "Therefore take good heed to yourselves. Since **you saw no form** on the
>   day that the LORD spoke to you at Horeb out of the midst of the fire,
>   beware lest you act corruptly by making a graven image for yourselves,
>   in the form of any figure, the likeness of male or female, the
>   likeness of any beast that is on the earth, the likeness of any winged
>   bird that flies in the air, the likeness of anything that creeps on
>   the ground, the likeness of any fish that is in the water under the
>   earth" (Deut 4:15-18).

Although someone could argue that the people didn't SEE a form of God but God may actually have one. That can be answered by the fact that God is a spirit (John 4:24). A "form" is a property of the **physical** world and not the spiritual world.

Comment: Many things are missing. You saw no form. Doesn't mean that God doesn't have a form. He may be on the other side of the mountain hidden. Also not making any graven images have nothing to do with God having no form. We do not worship every graven image we created right?

Comment: @SharenEayrs, I had already made that point.

Comment: It can also be pointed out on the "you saw no form" that this is Moses talking to the great mass of the people who indeed saw no form, while Moses and the 70 elders did see a form in Exodus 24:10.